# Keyboard typing random combination of two characters

Tags: keyboard

Whenever I Press the 'm' key the keyboard types random combination of 'm' and 'z' like 'mz', 'zmzz', 'zzmz' etc... the same thing happens when I press the 'u' key... Sometimes the keyboard types correctly but most of the time i'm facing this problem... Is there a solution to this problem?... I'm using ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS...

Comment: 99% this is not software problem. You can boot the BIOS or live session and test there. If you have the same problem there too, you need to replace your keyboard.

Comment: Probably YES ... get a new keyboard.